# Sum up elements to certain index and overwrite that value

Tags: python, algorithm

Is there a more pythonic way to do the following?

```
total = 0
for index, value in enumerate(frequencies):
    total += value
    frequencies[index] = total
```

Comment: What is `frequencies`? What is the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Python 2.x you can use a generator function(Note that this returns a new list):

```
def accumulate(lis):
    total = 0
    for item in lis:
        total += item
        yield total


>>> list(accumulate(range(5)))
[0, 1, 3, 6, 10]
```

On Python 3.x use [`itertools.accumulate`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate).

Answer (score 4):

For Python 3, use [itertools.accumulate](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
frequencies = list(itertools.accumulate(frequencies))
```

Your code is probably as Pythonic as it can get. One can easily understand what it does.

Comment: @hcwhsa oh, thanks, I've learned and used Python 3 ever since I started ☺.

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) contains an equivalent implementation that is remarkably similar to the original code by melbic :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything un-pythonic with what you wrote.  An alternative might be [numpy.cumsum()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html?highlight=cumsum#numpy.cumsum).

```
>>> 
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> a.cumsum()
array([ 0,  1,  3,  6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an inplace version and this is what exactly you are looking for, if you are using python 2.x.

```
frequencies = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(1, len(frequencies)): frequencies[i] += frequencies[i - 1]
print frequencies
```

**Output**

```
[1, 3, 6]
```